# Got stuck with creating a card game unicode histogram

Tags: python, unicode

I Have created a card game that shuffles a deck a deal 13 cards to 4 players,here is the code:

```
def shuffle_deck():
deck = []
for suit in ['H','C','D','S']:
    for denom in['A','2','3','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']:
        deck += [denom + suit]
random.shuffle(deck)
return deck

def deal_hand(n,deck):
    hand = []
    for i in range(n):
        card = deck.pop()
        hand += [card]
    return hand

def deal_cards(n,cards,deck):
    player = []
    for i in range(n):
        player.append(deal_hand(cards,deck))
    return player

def deal_hands():
    deck = shuffle_deck()
    players = deal_cards(4, 13,deck)
    print(players)
```

but i got stuck with  the histogram suppose to look for the heart and spades inside the four list output.Like this:

```
>>>print(hands) 
       [['8H','KC','KS','AC','QD','7H','7D','4D','9D','3H','KD','6H','9S'], 
        ['2C','7C','TC','2S','QC','6D','JC','5H','2H','8D','3D','7S','4H'], 
        ['8S','8C','JD','6S','3C','5C','AD','5D','2D','4C','QH','4S','AH'], 
        ['AS','9C','JS','QS','TH','JH','TS','3S','6C','5S','KH','9H','TD']] 

>>>card_histogram(hands)! 
        ❤❤❤❤          #four hearts in the first list   

        ❤❤❤            #three hearts in the second list 

        ❤❤             #two hearts in the third list

        ❤❤❤❤♠         #four heart and one spades in the fourth list
```

How to create that card_histogram function base on the code i wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the output you gave is correct for the input you provided, but, you should iterate through each sublist and count the number of cards of each suit, then do whatever printing you are supposed to.

```
def card_histogram(hands):
    for hand in hands:
        numHearts, numSpades, numClubs, numDiamonds = 0, 0, 0, 0
        for card in hand:
            if card[1] == 'H': numHearts += 1
            elif card[1] == 'S': numSpades += 1
            elif card[1] == 'C': numClubs += 1
            else: numDiamonds += 1
        for x in range(numHearts): print_heart()
        for x in range(numSpades): print_spade()
        # etc
```

Note that `card[1]` is subindexing the string and taking the 1-th (i.e. 2nd) character, which is what you know denotes the suit. The printing is pseudocode because I don't know what your expectations are wrt the printed unicode output, but if you are trying to print those unicode characters, you can probably type them directly into your file since in Python 3 the default file encoding is utf8 (someone please correct me if I am wrong).